# Escaping curly braces with angular.jstemplating in HTML <pre> environment

Tags: html, angularjs, pre, bibtex, templating-engine

I've found a strange, weird behavior with the `<pre>` tag in HTML when used in conjunction with angular.js' method of data binding via curly braces. Given the data binding `foo = 'bar'`, I want to write

```
<pre>
{{{foo}}}
</pre>
```

such that it prints

```
{bar}
```

within the `<pre>` environment.

It's no good to print `{ bar }`, with the spaces. (This is ultimately used to generate BibTeX.) I've tried using the html entities `&#123;` and `&#125;`, as well as the `<xmp>` environment.

Any idea what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try quoting the brackets:

```
{{ "{" + foo + "}" }}
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4LG6jfAAzzcw4tQuoTSw?p=preview

You also might try making a function:

```
$scope.q = function(s) {
   return "{" + s + "}";
 }

{{ q(foo) }}
```

Comment: No problem don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.  I also added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one of my Angular pages, and even using the suggestion in Angular's own error message didn't help me.

What *did* work was simply to replace the opening curly bracket with `&#123;` like this:

```
<pre>
.popup &#123;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
</pre>
```

This now shows the `<pre>` perfectly:

[image]

(By the way, this is the CSS you can use to easily vertically and horizontally center a `<div>` in the middle of your browser !)